# Inserting json data from jQuery ajax in to table as new row

Tags: php, json, jquery

I have been trying to add data from my ajax query that returns json data created in following mode:
    $lastedited = $_GET['lastload'];

```
$count = 1;
$JsonArray = Array();


while ($count <= 4) {  // luupataan x määrä ellei vastauksia tule.

$result = mysql_query("SELECT     RFQs.DateAdded as DateAdded,
                              Customers.Name as customer,
                              RFQs.ID as RFQID,
                              Suppliers.Name as supplier,
                              Ships.Name as ship,
                              RFQs.CustomerRef as CustomerRef,
                              Contacts.FirstName as contactF,
                              Contacts.LastName as contactL,
                              Contacts.Email as contactE,
                              Users.tunnus as handler,
                              RFQStatus.Name as status,
                              RFQs.Description
                   FROM       RFQs
                   LEFT JOIN  Ships ON RFQs.ShipID=Ships.ID
                   LEFT JOIN  Contacts ON RFQs.ContactID=Contacts.ID
                   LEFT JOIN  Customers ON RFQs.CustomerID=Customers.idCustomers
                   LEFT JOIN  Users ON RFQs.PriJobHandler=Users.id
                   LEFT JOIN  Suppliers ON RFQs.SupplierID=Suppliers.ID
                   LEFT JOIN  RFQStatus ON RFQs.StatusID=RFQStatus.ID
                   WHERE      RFQs.LastEdited > '$lastedited'
                  ") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  $count++;
  sleep(5);  // ei uusia rivejä, nukutaan 5 sekuntia ja yritetään uudelleen.
}else {
// käy rivit läpi ja pistää arrayyn  
  for ($x = 0, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result); $x < $numrows; $x++) {  
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  

    array_push($JsonArray, array("rivi" => array("ID" => $row["RFQID"],
                                        "DateAdded" => $row["DateAdded"], 
                                        "Supplier" => $row["supplier"], 
                                        "Customer" => $row["customer"], 
                                        "Ship" => $row["ship"],
                                        "CustomerRef" => $row["CustomerRef"],
                                        "Contact" => $row["contactF"]." ".$row["ContactL"],
                                        "Description" => $row["Description"],
                                        "PIC" => $row["handler"],
                                        "Status" => $row["status"])));  
}
$count = 6;
}

}
if ($count == 5) {
  echo "NO RESULTS!!";
}
else if ($count == 6) {
  //echo JSON to page  
  echo json_encode($JsonArray); 
}
```

My jQuery goes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function waitForMsg(lastload){
    if (lastload==null){
      lastload = { "lastload": "<?php echo $lastload; ?>" };
    } 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "GetUpdates.php",
        datatype: "json",
        data: lastload,
        async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
        cache: false,
        timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

        success: function(data){ /* kun tulokset saadaan niin suoritetaan.. */
            if (data=="NO RESULTS!!") {
            setTimeout(
                'waitForMsg()',
                1000
            );
            } else {
              displayrow(data.rivi);
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
            setTimeout(
                'waitForMsg()', /* Try again after.. */
                "15000"); /* milliseconds (15seconds) */
        },
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForMsg(); /* Start the inital request */
});

function displayrow(item)
{
  var tblRow =
            '<td id="showbutton-'+item.ID+'"><a href="#" onclick="hideShow(rowID'+item.ID+'">+</a></td>'
   +'<td id="DateAdded-'+item.ID+'">'+item.DateAdded+'</td>'
   +'<td id="Supplier-'+item.ID+'">'+item.Supplier+'</td>'
   +'<td id="Customer-'+item.ID+'">'+item.Customer+'</td>'
   +'<td id="Ship-'+item.ID+'">'+item.Ship+'</td>'
   +'<td id="CustomerRef-'+item.ID+'">'+item.CustomerRef+'</td>'
   +'<td id="Contact-'+item.ID+'">'+item.Contact+'</td>'
   +'<td id="Description-'+item.ID+'">'+item.Description+'</td>'
   +'<td id="PIC-'+item.ID+'">'+item.PIC+'</td>'
   +'<td id="Status-'+item.ID+'">'+item.Status+'</td>'
   +'<td id="Actions-'+item.ID+'">Hit F5 for actions</td>';
   $('#newRFQrowInput').before(tblRow);
}
</script>
```

Problem is I'm not sure how I should process this data coming back from ajax query.
At the moment all I'm getting is undefined.

Can some one help?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to encode it as json before passing it back to javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make changes in your .php file that send back information

```
$JsonArray = array("ID" => $row["RFQID"],
                    "DateAdded" => $row["DateAdded"], 
                    "Supplier" => $row["supplier"], 
                    "Customer" => $row["customer"], 
                    "Ship" => $row["ship"],
                    "CustomerRef" => $row["CustomerRef"],
                    "Contact" => $row["contactF"]." ".$row["ContactL"],
                    "Description" => $row["Description"],
                    "PIC" => $row["handler"],
                    "Status" => $row["status"]
            );
echo json_encode(array('rivi'=>$JsonArray));
```

**UPDATE:**

make changes in your "For loop"

```
$JsonArray = array();
for ($x = 0, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result); $x < $numrows; $x++) {  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        array_push($JsonArray,array("ID" => $row["RFQID"],
                                    "DateAdded" => $row["DateAdded"], 
                                    "Supplier" => $row["supplier"], 
                                    "Customer" => $row["customer"], 
                                    "Ship" => $row["ship"],
                                    "CustomerRef" => $row["CustomerRef"],
                                    "Contact" => $row["contactF"]." ".$row["ContactL"],
                                    "Description" => $row["Description"],
                                    "PIC" => $row["handler"],
                                    "Status" => $row["status"]
                                    )
                ); 
    }

}
```

Replace this with yours

```
else if ($count == 6) {
  //echo JSON to page  
  echo json_encode(array("rivi" =>$JsonArray)); 
}
```

and in ajax success function also.

```
success:function(data){
    if(data.rivi.length){
        //alert(data.rivi.length);
        displayrow(data.rivi);
    }               
}
```

Then at last in your displayrow function

```
function displayrow($item){
    var tblRow = '<table>';
    $.each($item,function(index,value){
        tblRow +='<tr><td id="showbutton-'+value.ID+'"><a href="#" onclick="hideShow(rowID'+value.ID+'">+</a></td>'
               +'<td id="DateAdded-'+value.ID+'">'+value.DateAdded+'</td>'
               +'<td id="Supplier-'+value.ID+'">'+value.Supplier+'</td>'
               +'<td id="Customer-'+value.ID+'">'+value.Customer+'</td>'
               +'<td id="Ship-'+value.ID+'">'+value.Ship+'</td>'
               +'<td id="CustomerRef-'+value.ID+'">'+value.CustomerRef+'</td>'
               +'<td id="Contact-'+value.ID+'">'+value.Contact+'</td>'
               +'<td id="Description-'+value.ID+'">'+value.Description+'</td>'
               +'<td id="PIC-'+value.ID+'">'+value.PIC+'</td>'
               +'<td id="Status-'+value.ID+'">'+value.Status+'</td>'
               +'<td id="Actions-'+value.ID+'">Hit F5 for actions</td></tr>';
    }   
   tblRow = '</table>';
   $('#newRFQrowInput').before(tblRow);
}
```

Comment: But what if my query returns multiple rows?

Comment: Just create multidimensional array and assign to $jsonArray. No need to make changes in last line. But if you are taking about multiple row then you need to make change in your displayrow function to iterate array properly. Right now it's only capable of handling single dimension array.

Comment: OK.. How to revise it so that it can handle multidimensional?
BTW. I updated my php example so that you can see it in full (naturally without connection part :D )

Comment: Currently data is coming out as follows: [{rivi:{ID:23, DateAdded:2012-02-10,...}}]

Comment: Thanks for such fulfilling response! I replaced all as you suggested, but still have error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined . This is for line = if(data.rivi.length){ from ajax success event. Any idea?

Comment: please try to execute your GetUpdates.php file on your server like  HOST_NAME/GetUpdates.php?lastload=_your_parameter. what it shows, any error message or proper object?

Comment: Problem was that I did not have json headers :D, After Some modification and debugging it is working now!!! big a BIG thanks!!!

Comment: @VikasNaranje won't the line tblRow = '</table>'; set tblRow to just '</table>'. Should it instead be tblRow += </table> ?

Answer (score 1):

write `echo json_encode($JsonArray);`  at the end of the page **GetUpdates.php**

if you are using **GET** method then I'll suggest to use use [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Your data coming this way

> [{rivi:{ID:23, DateAdded:2012-02-10,...}}]

so I made an example for you, rest is just logic

```
var jsonData = [{rivi:{ID:'23', DateAdded:'2012-02-10'}}];
alert(jsonData[0].rivi.ID); // will return 23
```

Comment: I have used   echo json_encode($JsonArray);  sorry for excluding it.

Comment: How much is $.getJSON different from what I'm using?
Thanks!

Comment: its easy, you need not to set `dataType` and  `Type`

Comment: OK .. maybe I'll use it next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you done

```
 json_encode( $JsonArray );
```

before returning it?

```
echo $JsonArray
```